# Does the construction of arithmetic toroidal compactification of $A_{g}$ depend on semistable reduction theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties

If there is a good theory of arithmetic toroidal compactification over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ of the Siegel modular variety with deep enough level structure, then it seems like semistable reduction theorem would automatically follow from the existence of compactification. However, I am still not sure whether the construction of arithmetic toroidal compactification (e.g. Faltings-Chai) uses semistable reduction theorem. It seems to me that the arithmetic toroidal compactification is constructed by gluing $A_{g}$ with Mumford's construction of degenerating abelian varieties for each "boundary component". In particular, the construction does not seem to require semistable reduction theorem, which sounds peculiar.

Comment: It is possible to prove the semistable reduction theorem (for curves and for Abelian varieties) using constructions such as geometric invariant theory (over an arbitrary base, as proved by Seshadri after Haboush), rather than by using Grothendieck's original proof in SGA, Artin-Winters, etc.  The point is that these constructions produce a moduli space that is manifestly projective, hence proper.  I do not know if this is what Faltings-Chai do, but one can do things that way (I believe Gieseker does this in lecture notes on geometric invariant theory).